# Какая версия CodeIgniter лучше?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Всем привет. Есть необходимость развернуть проект на CodeIgniter. Какая версия лучше 2 или 3. А то где то читал что 3-ая какая то глючная, а 2.2.6 стабильная версия. Что скажите?
P/s Да да, он старый фраймворк, да да на другом лучше, но по сабжу ПЛИЗ!

Comment: чем вызвана данная необходимость от того и отталкивайтесь. Разница в поддержке версий php, знания разработчиков.

Comment: Лучше 3 - вторая больше не поддерживается.

Comment: Я бы тоже на "тройке" делал.